# Deactivate weather server (aviationweather.gov) Mate 16.4

Tags: mate, weather

Since I've set a location in Ubuntu Mate, it's getting weather forecasts every few seconds. How can I disable it? I've already removed the location again, but Ubuntu still keeps getting information from aviationweather.gov. Would be glad for any tip for disabling it, because it's waking up my device all the time.

Comment: hi I think you can begin by checking your startup apps to see if the weather is still inside them (https://ubuntu-mate.community/uploads/default/optimized/2X/0/0982f220655cc5ffbff8e53ae9d25bc5b81c3f01_2_690x397.png). also did you already remove the idicator in the taskbar?

Comment: I've already removed the indicator. I also see no weather app in the startup configuration...

Answer (score 1):

I did [search for "*aviationweather.gov*" on Debian CodeSearch](https://codesearch.debian.net/search?q=aviationweather.gov&perpkg=1) and I see that this URL is used in the `libmateweather` package.

This library is used by MATE Panel. The weather is usually shown in two places - in the left part of the Clock and inside Calendar applet.

To switch off the polling do the right mouse click on *Clock* applet, select *Preferences* and uncheck *Show weather* checkbox on *General* tab:

[image: do not show weather]